# Finding text block with AWK and replace strings within

Tags: awk

I've got a terraform file and I need to find one or multiple resources blocks within it and modify  it or add it if it's missing.

**Sample Input** - An example how a file with 2 blocks might look (but could have more lines of data in each section):

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
    ami = "ami-0579a2723154bfc44"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    count = 1

    tags {
        Type = "ec2"
        By = "Terraform"
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
    ami = "ami-blahblah"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    count = 1
}
```

**Expected Output** - Given the above I'd expect the following output:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
    ami = "ami-0579a2723154bfc44"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    count = 1

    tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    map(
        Type = "ec2"
        By = "Terraform"
        )
    )
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
    ami = "ami-blahblah"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    count = 1

    tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    map(
        Type = "ec2"
        By = "Terraform"
        )
    )
}
```

So, instead of the curly brackets I need curved brackets and add *merge, var.tags* and *map(*. If there is no *tags* yet, I have to add the block (probably easier). I wrote a bash script around it, to be able to catch the specific use cases.

I've added a `declare` within the bash script having the tag information in case the resource block hasn't any. But I am totally happy to use any other solution here if it makes it easier.

```
ARRAY=( "Type:ec2"
        "By:Terraform")
```

The current awk I am using to find the resource blocks is ("i" starts with 0 and "k" with 1):

```
awk '/^resource "/ {i++}; i=='$i' && k=='$k' {print}; /^}/ {k++}' file
```

Can someone give me a hint? I guess I need to different awk's for each use case (replacing the tags or adding new one).
Need to go through many files like it and tried it with sed first and failed and got a bit further with awk, so hoping its actually the right tool to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in your shell array `ARRAY` don't match the format you want output, below I'm using an awk array for the defaults instead and using the desired output format for them. I'm also using different values from those already present in the first tags block in the input file so it's clear where they are coming from in the output.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("Type = \"bikini bottom\"" RS "By = \"Sponge Bob\"",dlftMap,RS)
    dfltIndent = "   "
}

$1 == "tags" {
    inTags = 1
    gotTags = 1
    indent = $0
    sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",indent)
    print indent "tags = merge("
    print indent "var.tags,"
    print indent "map("
    next
}

inTags && ($1 == "}") {
    print indent dfltIndent ")"
    print indent ")"
    inTags = 0
    next
}

$1 == "}" {
    if ( !gotTags ) {
        print ""
        print indent "tags = merge("
        print indent "var.tags,"
        print indent "map("
        for (i=1; i in dlftMap; i++) {
            print indent dfltIndent dlftMap[i]
        }
        print indent dfltIndent ")"
        print indent ")"
    }
    gotTags = 0
}

{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
    ami = "ami-0579a2723154bfc44"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    count = 1

    tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    map(
        Type = "ec2"
        By = "Terraform"
       )
    )
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
    ami = "ami-blahblah"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    count = 1

    tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    map(
       Type = "bikini bottom"
       By = "Sponge Bob"
       )
    )
}
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it! :) Haven't thought it's possible in a single awk. Will go through and try to understand it first thing in the morning. You cannot imagine how long I was sitting on that one the last days. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I THINK it's pretty clear but feel free to ask questions if you can't figure it out after adding a few prints to dump variables, checking the man pages, etc.